# Adding quantities of Duplicate Strings

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I've been tasked with sorting a list of categories. A shopping list, if you will. These categories are inputs from the user, items to be bought. After the string name of the category in question is input (using scanner of course) the user is then able to put in the quantity of that category (an integer), followed by the unit cost of that category(a double).
They are prompted to repeat this until the category they name is "end".

This is all fine and dandy, and I've already written code that takes all of this information and finds and prints out the largest cost item, the largest quantity item, and other info. What I need help with is my duplicate categories. For example, suppose the user puts in "cars" followed by an integer 3, followed by the number 24000.00. They then put in "refigerators" followed by 1, followed by 1300.00. And then the user puts in a duplicate of the first entry, which is "cars" followed by an integer 5, followed by the double 37000.00. How can I get my code revisit older entries, add the new quantity to the old one, and store that value without overriding the old stuff? I also need to find the largest average cost of the items in the list. I am new to HashMap, so I'm struggling with the code:  // create an arrayList to store values

```
              // create an arrayList to store values

            ArrayList<String> listOne = new ArrayList<String>();

            listOne.add("+ 1 item");

            listOne.add("+ 1 item");

            listOne.add("+ 1 item");



            // create list two and store values

            ArrayList<String> listTwo = new ArrayList<String>();

            listTwo.add("+1 item");

            listTwo.add("+1 item");



            // put values into map

            multiMap.put("some sort of user input detailing the name of the item", listOne);

            multiMap.put("some other input detailing the name of the next item", listTwo);
            // i need the user to input items until they type "end"

            // Get a set of the entries

            Set<Entry<String, ArrayList<String>>> setMap = multiMap.entrySet();

            // time for an iterator
            Iterator<Entry<String,  ArrayList<String>>> iteratorMap = setMap.iterator();        

           System.out.println("\nHashMap with Multiple Values");

            // display all the elements
                while(iteratorMap.hasNext()) {

                Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<String>> entry =

                        (Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<String>>) iteratorMap.next();

                String key = entry.getKey();

                List<String> values = entry.getValue();

              System.out.println("Key = '" + key + "' has values: " + values);

            }
    // all that up there gives me this:
```

HashMap with Multiple Values
Key = 'some other input detailing the name of the next item' has values: [+1 item, +1 item]
Key = 'some sort of user input detailing the name of the item' has values: [+ 1 item, + 1 item, + 1 item]

but I haven't given the user a chance to input the number of items or the cost.... I'm lost.

Comment: Set stores only unique values so when you get the setMap from multiMap.entrySet is a problem. since you have same value they would be stored only once ...

Comment: What does "I also need to find the largest average cost" mean? Average of what?

Comment: It means that if I have:

eggs 1 7.00,

milk 1 1.99,

eggs 2 2.50

then the program should print back that eggs had the largest average cost item: ie (7+5)/ 3 = 4

Comment: Does the example code in my answer solve the problem you are looking at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this small bit of sample code, it includes a Main class and two dependency classes, StatsPrinter and ShoppingEntry

```
package com.company;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String category;
        String quantity;
        String value;

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        HashMap<String, List<ShoppingEntry>> shoppingList = new HashMap<String, List<ShoppingEntry>>();

        while(true) {
            System.out.print("Enter the category of your item: ");
            category = bufferedReader.readLine();

            if("end".equals(category)){
                break;
            }

            System.out.print("Enter the quantity of your item: ");
            quantity = bufferedReader.readLine();

            System.out.print("Enter the value of your item: ");
            value = bufferedReader.readLine();

            if (shoppingList.containsKey(category)) {
                shoppingList.get(category).add(new ShoppingEntry(Integer.parseInt(quantity), Double.parseDouble(value)));
            }else{
                shoppingList.put(category, new ArrayList<ShoppingEntry>());
                shoppingList.get(category).add(new ShoppingEntry(Integer.parseInt(quantity),          Double.parseDouble(value)));
            }
        }

        StatsPrinter.printStatistics(shoppingList);
    }
}
```

and the ShoppingEntry class

```
package com.company;

public class ShoppingEntry {
    private int quantity;
    private double price;

    public ShoppingEntry(){
        quantity = 0;
        price = 0;
    }

    public ShoppingEntry(int quantity, double price){
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

and finally the StatsPrinter class, which leverages the data structure of the HashMap of ShoppingEntry's to print the desired statistics

```
package com.company;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class StatsPrinter {
    private static DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("#.##");

    public static void printStatistics(HashMap<String, List<ShoppingEntry>> shoppingList) {
        printNuumberOfItems(shoppingList);
        printLargestValue(shoppingList);
        printLargestAverage(shoppingList);
    }

    private static void printNuumberOfItems(HashMap<String, List<ShoppingEntry>> shoppingList) {
         System.out.println("There are " + shoppingList.keySet().size() + " items in your Shopping List");
     }

    private static void printLargestValue(HashMap<String, List<ShoppingEntry>> shoppingList) {
        double currentLargestPrice = 0;
        String largestPriceCategory = new String();

        for(String keyValue : shoppingList.keySet()) {
            for(ShoppingEntry entry : shoppingList.get(keyValue)) {
                if (entry.getPrice() > currentLargestPrice) {
                    currentLargestPrice = entry.getPrice();
                    largestPriceCategory = keyValue;
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println(largestPriceCategory + " has the largest value of: " +      format.format(currentLargestPrice));
     }

    private static void printLargestAverage(HashMap<String, List<ShoppingEntry>> shoppingList) {
        double currentLargestAverage = 0;
        String largestAverageCategory = new String();
        double totalCost = 0;
        int numberOfItems = 0;

        for(String keyValue : shoppingList.keySet()) {
            for(ShoppingEntry entry : shoppingList.get(keyValue)) {
                totalCost += entry.getPrice();
                numberOfItems += entry.getQuantity();
            }
            if((totalCost / numberOfItems) > currentLargestAverage) {
                currentLargestAverage = totalCost / numberOfItems;
                largestAverageCategory = keyValue;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(largestAverageCategory + " has the largest average value of: " +     format.format(currentLargestAverage));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of manipulating three separate values, create a class called `Item`. Implement the `Comparable` interface such that two Items are equal if they share a common name.  See the [Javadoc for Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) for instructions on defining the interface.

```
public class Item implements Comparable { 
    [...] 
}
```

Create a list of items.

```
List<Item> shoppingList;
```

When you want to add an item to the list, check if the list already contains it first.

```
// If it's already in the list, add their quantities together
if (shoppingList.contains(newItem))
    shoppingList.get(newItem).quantity += newItem.quantity
// Otherwise, add it to the list
else
    shoppingList.add(newItem);
```